# Base64 String throwing invalid character error

Tags: c#, string, ado.net, base64, invalid-characters

I keep getting a Base64 invalid character error even though I shouldn't.

The program takes an XML file and exports it to a document. If the user wants, it will compress the file as well. The compression works fine and returns a Base64 String which is encoded into UTF-8 and written to a file.

When its time to reload the document into the program I have to check whether its compressed or not, the code is simply:

```
byte[] gzBuffer = System.Convert.FromBase64String(text);
return "1F-8B-08" == BitConverter.ToString(new List<Byte>(gzBuffer).GetRange(4, 3).ToArray());
```

It checks the beginning of the string to see if it has GZips code in it.

Now the thing is, all my tests work. I take a string, compress it, decompress it, and compare it to the original. The problem is when I get the string returned from an ADO Recordset. The string is exactly what was written to the file (with the addition of a "\0" at the end, but I don't think that even does anything, even trimmed off it still throws). I even copy and pasted the entire string into a test method and compress/decompress that. Works fine.

The tests will pass but the code will fail using the exact same string? The only difference is instead of just declaring a regular string and passing it in I'm getting one returned from a recordset.

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would probably help if you'd post an example of a string that you're passing to Convert.FromBase64String (e.g. what you get on output if you put a Debug.Write directly before the call)

Comment: ...even if you posted the first and last 8 or so bytes, and the string length, that would probably be enough to see that the string is the correct format.

Comment: qGcAAB+LCA ... cAAA==

Its 2376 characters long.

Comment: Are you still getting a FormatException:Invalid Characters, or is it a different exception?

Comment: ... I guess you must have figured out what the problem was?

Comment: Yes, the \0 was actually the problem. (Well, one of them). I didn't see that as the issue in the tests because the parent method the tests call consider a non-base64 string an unformatted file. But all is well now, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You say

> The string is exactly what was written
>   to the file (with the addition of a
>   "\0" at the end, but I don't think
>   that even does anything).

In fact, it does do something (it causes your code to throw a `FormatException`:"Invalid character in a Base-64 string") because the [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) does not consider "\0" to be a valid Base64 character.

```
  byte[] data1 = Convert.FromBase64String("AAAA\0"); // Throws exception
  byte[] data2 = Convert.FromBase64String("AAAA");   // Works
```

**Solution: Get rid of the zero termination.**  (Maybe call `.Trim("\0")`)

**Notes**:

The [MSDN docs for `Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) say it will throw a `FormatException` when

> The length of s, ignoring white space
>   characters, is not zero or a multiple
>   of 4.
>
> -or-
>
> The format of s is invalid. s contains a non-base 64 character, more
>   than two padding characters, or a
>   non-white space character among the
>   padding characters.

and that

> The base 64 digits in ascending order
>   from zero are the uppercase characters
>   'A' to 'Z', lowercase characters 'a'
>   to 'z', numerals '0' to '9', and the
>   symbols '+' and '/'.

Comment: I trim the \0 off, it still throws.

Comment: It still throws a FormatException, or something else?  What is the exact string being passed to FromBase64String?

Comment: The exact string is a little bit long to post. Is there a size limit I don't know about? What is there is valid though, I checked it for any characters not allowed in Base64. Maybe I just did the trim wrong, although it doesn't explain why the tests are running fine.

Comment: @Brandon: Is the length a multiple of 4?  Honestly, even if you posted the first and last 8 bytes, and the string length, that would probably be enough to see that the string is the correct format.

Comment: It is a multiple of 4, and I'm assuming the == at the end of the string (see my response to the original post) is there just for padding purposes?

Comment: @Brandon: Yeah, it makes the length a multiple of 4

Answer (score 3):

Whether null char is allowed or not really depends on base64 codec in question.
Given vagueness of Base64 standard (there is no authoritative exact specification), many implementations would just ignore it as white space. And then others can flag it as a problem. And buggiest ones wouldn't notice and would happily try decoding it... :-/

But it sounds c# implementation does not like it (which is one valid approach) so if removing it helps, that should be done.

One minor additional comment: UTF-8 is not a requirement, ISO-8859-x aka Latin-x, and 7-bit Ascii would work as well. This because Base64 was specifically designed to only use 7-bit subset which works with all 7-bit ascii compatible encodings.

Answer (score 1):

```
string stringToDecrypt = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.ToString()
```

//change to 
string stringToDecrypt = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.ToString())

Answer (score 0):

If removing \0 from the end of string is impossible, you can add your own character for each string you encode, and remove it on decode.

Answer (score 0):

One gotcha to do with converting Base64 from a string is that some conversion functions use the preceding "data:image/jpg;base64," and others only accept the actual data.