# Base 64 decoding issue with special characters

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, base64

I have used Base 64 files from the below link to decode my response that I receive from server:
[nicklockwood / Base64](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64)

But somehow it fails when it encouters special characters. How can I solve this issue. It works when I tried it with Hex both server side and clienct side.

Comment: Can you show us how you get your data ? Is it a valid string ? If it's possible, could you show us a base64 string that fails decoding ?

Comment: "Special Characters" implies that the server is sending you encodes Unicode chars?

Comment: Yes. I receive _ - in my reponse. Based on this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926513/decode-java-encoded-base64-string-in-c-sharp#comment19199254_13926513 ... I am replacing the values with + /. Hope it works.

Comment: So, did it work ? If so, answer to yourself, it might help other users.

Answer (score 0):

I have folled the below link:

[Decode Java encoded Base64 string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926513/decode-java-encoded-base64-string-in-c-sharp#comment19199254_13926513)

and replaced - and _ that Java uses with the + and / that C# uses. It worked.

Comment: If your answer worked, you may want to mark your answer as the correct solution to the problem.